# VelocityEngine removes escape characters from string

Tags: java, escaping, velocity

When I call:

`velocityEngine.evaluate(velocityContext, writer, "", template);`

with `parameter.querystring` =  `{"hi": "\"hello\""}`

after evaluation `writer` contains `{"hi": ""hello""}`

**Question:**

- Why does Velocity remove escaping characters?
- How can I prevent removal of escaping characters?

Comment: I don't know VelocityEngine, so I can't help you with your first question. As for the second, does `{"hi": "\\\"hello\\\""}` as  `parameter.querystring` help?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, yes `"\\\"hello\\\""` helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: I don't know VelocityEngine, so take this with a grain of salt.

> Why does Velocity remove escaping characters?

Most likely VelocityEngine reads the values in `parameter.querystring` JSON as individual String. So the String `"\"hello\""` is read as the text `"hello"`. Then later in the writer, it simply pastes this String back as is.

Personally I see this as a flaw in the source code of the writer, which should have used something along the lines of [`Pattern.quote(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) to escape all characters before inserting it.

> How can I prevent removal of escaping characters?

An additional escaped `\` can be added manually as a work-around for the behavior of the writer. So your `parameter.querystring` would become:

```
{"hi": "\\\"hello\\\""}
```

Basically the text `\"hello\"`, where both the `\` and `"` characters are escaped with an additional `\` to put it in the java String.